# Capturing proma image in android camera

Tags: java, image, camera, 360-degrees

So i have creating a project there have a function to capture 360° image i mean proma image in android studio in android app using java so if there anyone please give the answer it will very helpful.

I have say the same things to many seniors if there have time then they says that they will send it in future and some serious have not enough time to complete the work for me but there i have not enough time for wait i need to submit the project in middle of March, so if there have anyone who is just complete the function please send the answer

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.